# Не могу получить коллекцию Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, view, eloquent

помогите пожалуйста, я не могу понять в чем проблема.
Пытаюсь вернуть во вьюшку коллекцию персонажей находящихся на аккаунте.
Но во вьюшке он мне выводит You dont have a characters!

HomeController

```
public function index()
{
    $account = Auth::user()->account;
    $roles = DB::select('select * from user_data where account_name = ?', [$account]);
    return view('home', ['roles' => $roles]);
}
```

home.blade.php

```
<div class="panel-body">
                You are logged in!
                @if ( count( $roles ) > 0 )
                    @foreach ( $roles as $role )
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ $role['lev'] }}</span> {{ $role['char_name'] }}
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <li class="list-group-item text-center">You dont have a characters!</li>
                @endif
            </div>
```

Comment: `->get()` что бы у запроса получить коллекцию

Comment: И лучше используйте связи, откажитесь от сырых запросов тем паче в контроллере